# Why Inherited AttributeUsage is false for DataContractAttribute?

Tags: c#, datacontract

When I read the [DataContractAttribute](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataContractAttribute.cs,474ac02000d34103) source code, I noticed Inherited = false in AttributeUsage. Anyone know why need to set Inherited to false?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DataContractAttribute : Attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

"The Inherited property indicates whether your attribute can be inherited by classes that are derived from the classes to which your attribute is applied. This property takes either a true (the default) or false flag." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/84c42s56(v=vs.100)